# Can some values of DATETIME2(2) compare less than itself?

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL script of several steps that imports some data into a table and then summarizes what happened. It executes inside a single transaction. The table of interest has a column declared `[TimeLastSeen] DATETIME2(2)`. At the start of the script I declare

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME2(2) = GetDate();
```

and use that consistently through the script in place of GetDate(). `@now` is assigned once and never changed.

When I import the data, I have (inside a large `MERGE` statement)

```
UPDATE ... SET [TimeLastSeen] = @now
```

and then a subsequent statement checks for records not seen in this import:

```
INSERT INTO #MergeResult ([Action], [TargetId], [TargetBusinessName], [TargetLicenseNumber])
SELECT 'MISSED', [Id], [BusinessName], [LicenseNumber]
FROM [Providers]
WHERE [TimeLastSeen] < @now;
```

This ran fine several times, but then one time it updated all the records, but reported that all the imported rows were missed. So first it `SET [TimeLastSeen] = @now` on every record in the table, and then `WHERE [TimeLastSeen] < @now` was true for every record, for the same value of `@now`.

I re-ran the script on the same import file, and it worked properly -- nothing matched `WHERE [TimeLastSeen] < @now`

So can some values of DATETIME2(2) evaluate as less than itself? Is the fix to declare greater precision, like DATETIME2(6), or do I add

```
DECLARE @justBeforeNow DATETIME2(6) = DATEADD(millisecond, -1, @now);
```

and use that value in the comparison?

Comment: The problem likely isn't `datetime2` here, it's that you are using `GETDATE()` which is a **`datetime`**. When comparing a `datetime` to a `datetime2` it is *strongly* recommended you explicitly `CONVERT` the value to a `datetime2` with the appropriate precision. Or, likely better, perhaps you should be using `SYSDATETIME()`, which returns a `datetime2(7)`.

Comment: @Larnu's comment should be an answer. Very related to this, check that all your Datetime2 values are set to use the same precision--if you left off that (2), the default is (7), and then you have to worry how the rounding will play out.

Comment: As an example, try `SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime2(3), '2022-07-15T17:20:38.123') = CONVERT(datetime, '2022-07-15T17:20:38.123') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` Notice that you get `0` *not* `1`. even though the 2 values have the **same** literal value. This, however, returns `1`: `SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime2(3), '2022-07-15T17:20:38.120') = CONVERT(datetime2(3),CONVERT(datetime, '2022-07-15T17:20:38.120')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=876f6b4c7528da01b6fd5a1ba8e026d9)

Comment: I doubled-checked that it's DATETIME2(2) everywhere. There's only a single conversion, when `@now` is assigned. But in any case, I added a proper conversion: `DECLARE @now DATETIME2(2) = CONVERT(DATETIME2(2), GetDate())`

Comment: What is the exact data type and precision of `TimeLastSeen`

Comment: Everything is DATETIME2(2). There's a single conversion of GetDate, and all other comparisons are betweween DATETIME2(2) values.